# MySQL - dont show any duplicates row

Tags: sql, duplicates

i have two tables :

```
table1
id | column1
1  | a
2  | b
3  | c

table2
id | column1
1  | a
2  | b
3  | d
```

I want to display only :

```
3 |d
3 |c
```

so far i try use :

```
SELECT column1 FROM `table1` UNION DISTINCT SELECT column1 FROM `table2`
```

in result i have unique values but i want that : if there are duplicates values in that two tables dont show any of them

edit 
sorry i have  missitake in output

Comment: What about `3 | c` ? What is your RDBMS?

Comment: Add some more table data to make it a bit more complex, e.g. (1,c), (4,a) to table1.

Comment: ok i do some misstake . Of course in output should be 3|c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was simple:
 select column1 from table1 where column1 not in (select column1 from table2 )

Above is syntax for MySQL

thanks for quide me

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from
(
    select * from table1
    union all
    select * from table2
)
except all
(
    select * from table1
    intersect all
    select * from table2
)
```

The first sub-query (with `UNION ALL`) returns all rows from both tables.

The second sub-query (with `INTERSECT ALL`) returns the tables' common rows.

Take the all rows (`UNION ALL` result) and remove the common rows (`INTERSECT ALL` rows) using `EXCEPT ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve this?

```
SELECT ISNULL(table1.id, table2.id) AS id, ISNULL(table1.column1, table2.column1) AS column1
FROM table1
  FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.column1 = table2.column1
WHERE (table1.column1 IS NULL AND table2.column1 IS NOT NULL)
  OR (table1.column1 IS NOT NULL AND table2.column1 IS NULL);
```

If not, please provide more data and info on what exactly you mean by a *duplicate*.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want values outside of your union right ?

What about :

```
SELECT column1 FROM `table 1`, `table 2` 
MINUS (or EXCEPT, depending on your dbms)
SELECT column1 FROM `table1` UNION SELECT column1 FROM `table2`
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

The first query is showing records from the table1 that are not present in the table2 and the second one records from the table2 that are not present in the table1. Union all is used to combine the result-set of two queries.

```
    select id, column from table1
    where (id, column) not in (select id, column from table2)
    union all
    select id, column from table2
    where (id, column) not in (select id, column from table1)
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered as low quality answers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think that in this case this simple code does not need explanations.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: You convinced me :)